Missing read access to /etc/chrony/chrony.keys and Cannot open /var/log/chrony/tracking.log due to permission denied
i hope this post finds you well, i have a three NTP servers ( two chrony , and one ntpsec ) , that peer to peer to each , the problem is when i pass to authentication ( symmetric key between ntp servers ), when i run sudo systemctl restart chronyd it always :
]: chronyd version 4.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP ]: Wrong owner of /run/chrony (UID = 110)
1: Disabled command socket /run/chrony/chronyd.sock
]: Loaded 2 symmetric keys
]
]: Missing read access to /etc/chrony/chrony.keys: Permission denied Initial frequency -4.700 ppm
]: Could not open /var/log/chrony/tracking.log Permission denied
]: Loaded seccomp filter (level 1)
Started chrony.service- chrony, an NTP client/server.
]: Could not open /var/log/chrony/measurements.log: Permission denied

whoever i do :
>  sudo useradd -r -s /usr/sbin/nologin -d /var/lib/chrony -U chrony
> sudo chown -R chrony:chrony /etc/chrony sudo chown -R chrony:chrony
> /var/log/chrony sudo chown -R chrony:chrony /var/lib/chrony sudo chown
> -R chrony:chrony /run/chrony sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/chrony sudo chmod -R 750 /var/lib/chrony sudo chmod -R 750 /run/chrony sudo chmod
> 640 /etc/chrony/chrony.keys


Please edit your question to add which Linux distribution and version had the permission problems when restarted chrony.  Can tell Linux because of systemd, but they differ on security modules which changes what could be denying access.

first thank you sir for your answer, and i don't know why i try the edit the post but doesn't work , i use ubuntu sever live 2024  24.4

You do not yet have the reputation on this site for edits to appear immediately. Also mention which distro in a comment, which is not ideal but we can proceed with checking either selinux or apparmor.
